# Dired up to parent directory on symlink

Tags: helm, dired

I have a symlink

```
~/link -> ~/a/really/long/path
```

When I press `^` in the buffer, it takes me to

```
~
```

but I want to go to

```
~/a/really/long
```

Is there a right way to do this?

Another question is, if I'm on a symlink file's buffer, how can I find out the buffer's physical path?

Say I'm reading a markdown file `~/a/really/long/path/readme.md`, what command can print out the physical path of it?

Comment: Is `RET ^` not good enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of a command to do this, or a setting that you can modify to make `^` do it.

I'm on MS Windows without symlinks, but you might try defining a command that uses the same definition as `dired-up-directory` but that converts `dired-current-directory` to its symlink target by wrapping it in **`file-truename`**, which follows symlinks (untested):

```el
;; Same as `dired-up-directory', except for wrapping with `file-truename'.
(defun my-dired-up-directory (&optional other-window)
  "Run Dired on parent directory of current directory.
Follows symlinks for current directory.
Find the parent directory either in this buffer or another buffer.
Creates a buffer if necessary.
If OTHER-WINDOW (the optional prefix arg), display the parent
directory in another window."
  (interactive "P")
  (let* ((dir  (file-truename (dired-current-directory)))
         (up   (file-name-directory (directory-file-name dir))))
    (or (dired-goto-file (directory-file-name dir))
        ;; Only try dired-goto-subdir if buffer has more than one dir.
        (and (cdr dired-subdir-alist)  (dired-goto-subdir up))
        (progn (if other-window (dired-other-window up) (dired up))
               (dired-goto-file dir)))))
```

---

If no one offers an existing way to do this, you might want to file an enhancement request to make `dired-up-directory` be able to do this (i.e., optionally).  That could be done via a particular prefix-arg value or via a variable binding.  Alternatively, you could just ask for such an alternative command, so users can bind it to a key.

Comment: Nice code! Thanks for your advice:D

Comment: @Drew How can you do this to also follow the symlink down a directory?

Comment: @Drew I can post a new question but I think it is a really simple change and I'm not sure of a function to do this.